# How to see a historical graph of Jenkins task / build / item duration?

Tags: performance, jenkins, graph, duration

I've seen that perhaps xUnit, TeamCity and possibly JUnit can graph test duration, if you are writing those tests, but how can I graph all of my items historical durations? I know there are some complicated graphing plugins that you can set up, and you can spend time writing out the durations to an extra file, and time binding the performance plugins to those, but I want something "out of the box" that just shows the durations, without writing and reading my own duration caches.

Bonus points if it shows on the main dashboard screen. I see Jenkins has the "Last Duration" on there already, but a sparkline of historical duration would be *great*

Answer (score 5):

Apparently *this is built-in* to Jenkins. There's a `trend` button I never noticed in the build history that shows the graph. Would be nice to see a nice sparkline on the dashboard though

[image]

[image]

Comment: I actually only realized through your post that the `trend` button has its own link, and is different from the triangle button next to it.